# 2013 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

This is an alternative form of the Town Hall Chat system we've done [in previous elections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169754/february-2013-stack-overflow-moderator-election-town-hall-chat), we're trying some new things to test out how a different approach works.

Here's how it'll work.

- During the nomination phase, (so, until June 17th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current.
- At the end of the phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. That said, if I have concerns about any questions in this fashion, I will be sure to point this out in comments before the decision making time.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this new process, feel free to post as a comment here.

---

The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/2013-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).

Answer (score 8):

One of the biggest schisms the site has is the divide between the experienced developers who are active on the site and the mass of inexperienced but enthusiastic people wanting to develop games.  What is your stance on the issue, and what role, if any, do you see diamond mods as having on making sure the site remains a useful tool for getting answers to game dev questions?

Comment: The issue of...? The ratio between experienced developers and inexperienced developers? The flood of "getting started" questions?

Comment: Take your pick, there are a lot of discussions on meta already that touch on the issues.  e.g.  http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/542/request-relax-a-bit-on-moderation-and-dont-be-so-eager-to-shut-down-questions?rq=1  http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/826/getting-started-questions-shouldnt-we-have-something-for-this?rq=1 http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/879/12-hours-of-gdse-is-quality-going-downhill?rq=1 http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/985/should-we-be-more-exclusive?rq=1 I purposely left it vague to let people fill in the blank.

Answer (score 5):

How do you compare against the other candidates?

Comment: +1 But I liked your unicorn question too!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Comment: Cynical, just how I like it. :D

Answer (score 3):

Do you want to make this site more friendly to newcomers and beginners? If yes, how do you want to do it when these people are most likely to ask questions, [that are discouraged here](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1165/30949)?

Comment: It's much better to post these as separate questions, so they can be voted on separately. My example was a little different, as it contains two questions that will definitely be on the list, followed by three more that _might_ get on the list if we don't collect enough questions here. Please go ahead and add two more answers - these are good questions!

Comment: Alright, edited this one and posted two more :)

Comment: This is truly meta when you say: Add two more answers with questions.

Comment: There are infinite levels of meta. I just meta'd your meta on my meta. Yeah, meta.

Answer (score 3):

Being a moderator will definitely take some of your time. Candidates are usually people with reputation gained by answering questions. Are you still going to take the same time to actually answer questions? Or are we losing some of the great answers because you are becoming a mod?

Answer (score 3):

Aren't you afraid, that you will burn out solving mundane issues that you could ignore before?

Comment: I'd replace the word "stupid" with "mundane" since that's most of what moderators do. Deal with boring stuff.

Comment: I'll add it to my vocabulary, thanks.